# Getting close to zero percent of particles with energy greater than an activation energy of 101kJ/mol using the Maxwell-Boltzmann energy distribution

Tags: kinetics, statistical-mechanics

I experimentally obtained the activation energy of a reaction to be approximately 101kJ/mol. I was then going to use the value for the activation energy to see how the number of particles with sufficient energy to undergo a successful reaction changes with temperature using the Maxwell-Boltzmann energy distribution. However, I noticed that the graph already approaches zero close to 10kJ/mol. I attached a photo of the equation and graph.
[image: Maxwell-Boltzmann energy distribution equation, Boltzmann-Constant, Graph]

Am I doing something wrong?
I am certain that the activation energy of the reaction I am studying is around 100kJ/mol and that a reaction really does occur.

Another question, what does the y-axis really represent?

I graphed the proportion of particles with sufficient activation energy vs. temperature in Kelvin and I found that it increase exponentially. So exponentially that it seems almost vertical. Here is a picture of it. I could also have made a mistake though.

[image: proportion of particles vs. temperature]

Comment: So what if only $1\over1000$ of all molecules are able to react at any given moment? We'll wait a few moments longer, that's all.

Comment: With typically $10^{10}$ collisions /second  and 1/1000 with enough energy is still a huge number of collisions and will be a pretty fast reaction.

Comment: Oh right, thank you both for your answers. I got the proportion of particles with sufficient energy but the values that I got were to the order of 10^{-52}. Is that unusual? @porphyrin , Ivan Neretin

Comment: Well this is a tiny, tiny number, and so small that even with a mole of reactants you will have to wait, and wait, and wait...

Comment: I see. Is that number usual? Actually, are activation energies of around 100kJ usual?

Comment: Large but not unusual. I calculated a fraction $\approx 7\cdot 10^{-22}$  at 280 K using the energy equation as given by Wikipedia and 100 kJ/mol, but you should check my calc I may have made an error.

Comment: I see. Perhaps I used the wrong method? I did the integral of f(x) with the activation energy as the lower boundary over the integral of f(x) lower boundary, 0. Could I please have the link to that Wikipedia page? I can't seem to google it.

Comment: Nevermind, sorry. The values increased exponentially after 100K. The fraction I calculated with an Ea of 101 was $1.08*10^{-18}. I suppose that would be more "normal." It's quite interesting how it increases so suddenly. I edited the original post to add the graph of my results. My equations could be wrong too, though.

Comment: @porphyrin Is not 1 degree of freedom energy distribution more appropriate than 3 degrees of M-B distribution ? Like the Ke for motion perpendicular to direction to the other molecule do not really contribute much to the reaction activation, if the frontal attack to overcome potential barrier is expected. ( But I am too long out of Academia to be a good theorist. )

Comment: @Poutnik, yes that would be better. The effect is probably small, however,  as the exponential will dominate.

Comment: See [hyperphysics : Velocity Distribution in One Dimension](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Kinetic/maxspe.html#c2)  $$f(v)=\sqrt{\frac{m}{2\pi kT}} \exp {\frac{-mv^2}{2kT}}$$ with the maximum at $v=0$

Comment: You might find it helpful to replot the lower plot with a log scale on the y-axis and a narrower range of T on the x-axis.

Comment: @Andrew Yes!! That was extremely helpful! Thank you so much!